# Query parameters override route parameters in .NET WebApi 4. How to avoid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have more or less standard route for webapi (except I added {action}):

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The problem starts when I have a controller, that should accept any (zero or more, with random names) query parameters. Say it works with GET HTTP to URL like:

```
/api/Data/2836581?id=3&name=lol&etc=23&filter=all_but_nice
```

In the Get(int id) controller method I receive id==3, while I expected id==2836581.

I can bypass this using:

```
Request.GetRouteData().Values["id"]; // 2836581
Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs(); // All query parameters
```

But this solutions feels more like a HACK rather than "happy-path".

Can I make WebApi prioritize route variables over url-query params?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this I add a check in `AuthorizationFilterAttribute` to reject this sort of request.

```
private static void dedupQuery( HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    var routeData = actionContext.Request.GetRouteData().Values;
    var queryString = actionContext.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
    if( queryString.Keys.Any(s => routeData.Keys.Contains(s)))
    {
        throw new HttpException((int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict, "DUPLICATED PARAM");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the name of the parameter "id=3" to "anotherId=3"

Comment: Query params names are almost random. I do not have control over them.

Comment: I could rename route variable id => idAndARandomString, but what happens if I get ?idAndARandomString=12 another day?

Comment: try to change "id" to "itemid" in your rout definition: routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{itemid}/{action}",

Comment: I don't like "renaming" solution: First, I have other controllers, where variable name "id" fits perfectly. Second, I don't have control over query-parmeters.

Comment: Unfortunately we are not always doing what we like. You have two parameters with same name. I believe that "I do not like to name different parameters with same name" goes hire in priority list.